# How to find the smallest and largest value from this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array which stores the values in the array in this format

```
Array
(
        [0] => 0,20
        [1] => 21,50
        [2] => 201,300
        [3] => 301,400
)
```

now how will I find the smallest and the largest numeric value from it ?

Comment: Will array always be in same format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need minimum and maximum range.

For minimum and maximum range, first walk through array and replace

`,` by `.` so that they become numbers (comparable).

Them find out `min()` and `max()` of the resulting array.

Find out the key where the elements sit.

Now, access the elements of the original array with these keys.

```
<?php
$org = $result = Array(
        '0,20',
        '21,50',
        '201,300',
        '301,400',
);

$result = array_map(function($el) {
    return str_replace(',','.',$el); }, $result
                   );
echo '<pre>';
$minKey = array_search(min($result), $result);
$maxKey = array_search(max($result), $result);

$min2 = $org[$minKey]; // Returns 0,20
$temp = explode(',', $min2);
$min = $temp[0];
echo $min; // Prints 0

echo "<br/>";
$max2 = $org[$maxKey]; // Returns 301,400
$temp = explode(',', $max2);
$max = $temp[1];
echo $max; // Prints 400
?>
```

Comment: I want it to return smallest value from it like 0, and then max 400

Comment: I have changed answer depending upon the format you have specified. Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($a as $val)
{
    $exploded_val = explode(",",$val);
    $final_array[] = $exploded_val[0];
    $final_array[] = $exploded_val[1];
}

sort($final_array);

$min = $final_array[0];
$max = $final_array[count($final_array)-1];

echo $min.'>>'.$max;
```

Comment: No order might differ it may also become something like this                       Array
(
    [0] => 51,100
    [1] => 0,20
    [2] => 301,400
    [3] => 401,500
)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [min](http://php.net/manual/de/function.min.php) and [max](http://php.net/manual/de/function.max.php) functions?

Answer (score 0):

You should watch out how you store your data... If I understood well, you just need to explode the array values, to mount a proper array and then use [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) functions.

Something like this:

```
$ar = array("0,20","21,50","201,300","301,400");
foreach ($ar as $el) {
    $el = explode(",", $el);
    $result[] = $el[0];
    $result[] = $el[1];
}

echo "min: ".min($result)."\n";
echo "max: ".max($result);
```